# Как сделать выборку без подзапросов в mysql...

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть такая таблица MySql http://s019.radikal.ru/i623/1404/11/aeb75a31ce4f.jpg

Нужно выбрать item_id, у которой option_id = 17,18,14 т.е 60
Можно ли это выполнить одним sql запросом?

Примечание: при составления запроса известно только option_id = 17,18,14, а определить нужно item_id у которой в целом есть такой набор опций.

Спасибо!

[ссылка](http://s019.radikal.ru/i623/1404/11/aeb75a31ce4f.jpg)

Comment: @tralvor, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. Приведите код и вашу таблице вместо публикации ссылки на изображение.

Answer (score 1):

например так

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM table WHERE option_id IN (17,18,14)
```

Кстати, тут я немного затупил.

1. Покажите связанные с этой таблицы.
2. **Что-то я не вижу логики вытягивать item_id с этой таблицы. Обычно по item_id вытаскивают данные**
3. Вангую, что где-то вам нужен LEFT JOIN или просто JOIN

Comment: 17 И 18 И 14 (не ИЛИ) - хотел уточнить

Comment: т.е результат должен быть только item_id = 60

Comment: @tralvor, вот как раз таки IN это, грубо говоря, аналог WHERE option_id = 17 AND option_id = 18 AND option_id = 14

Выполните запрос, что я написал в ответе и увидите результат

Comment: БД сам спроектировал, нужно вытащить id Товаров, которые принадлежат к данным опциям (характеристикам)

Comment: @tralvor, добавьте к своему запросу DISTINCT

Comment: @tralvor, он выбирает уникальные. зачем вам в результате 58, 58, 59, 59 ???

Comment: перечитайте внимательней вопрос - результат должен быть только item_id = 60 т.к этот товар содержит все опции в целом (17,18)

Comment: "
@tralvor, вот как раз таки IN это, грубо говоря, аналог WHERE option_id = 17 AND option_id = 18 AND option_id = 14"

Уважаемый, mountpoint запрос WHERE IN как раз таки заменяет OR, он выведете те товары, где оптионИД соответствует предоставленным в списке.